# replace remote control for ceiling fan with light to wall switches

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

How do I use existing double pole wall switch for ceiling fan with light kit when replacing with Casa Viejo Revue that only has remote control? I don't want the remote control feature but the fan does not have manual speed control hanging chain like the current one. Can I NOT install the provided receiver (and remote control) and instead use an after market wall mounted fan speed controller/on-off and a separate on-off light switch?

---

Currently the wall double pole plastic switch box has a 12-2 from the wall plugs and a 12-3 out to ceiling fan/light box in the ceiling. The white commons (12-2 & 12-3) are spliced together and wire nutted in the box. The black 12-2 is spliced and wire nutted in the box with two black wires; one leading from the splice to the fan switch and the other to the light switch. The fan switch also has the 12-3 black attached to it. The light switch has the red 12-3 attached to it. The 12-2 green ground is attached to the fan switch and the 12-3 green ground is attached to the light switch.

Answer (score 1):

What you propose is indeed possible. How difficult it is, depends on what wiring is currently in place.

---

You should start by connecting all the bare/green grounding conductors in the switch box together, including a pigtail to both switches. Other than that, it sounds like the wiring in the switch box is good to go.

If you want to control the fan with a wall fan control, you can install that in place of the fan toggle switch.

In the ceiling box, you'll likely find the 12/3 cable from the switch box. If the existing fixture uses a remote module, you'll likely find that either the black or red wire from the 12/3 cable is simply capped off. You'll see the black/red, white and ground wire connect to the remote module. The remote module should connect to the fixture with a black, blue, white, and bare/green wire.

If you want to remove the remote module, you should disconnect it from all the wiring. Once disconnected, you can remove the module, or cap off all the wires and leave the module in place.

To control the fan using only the wall switches.

- Connect the white wire from the ceiling to the white wire from the fixture.
- Connect the bare/green wire from the ceiling to the bare/green wire from the fixture. If the box is metal, include a pigtail to the box.
- Connect the red wire from the ceiling to the blue wire from the fixture.
- Connect the black wire from the ceiling to the black wire from the fixture.

Now the switch connected to the red wire, should turn the light on/off. The switch connected to the black wire, should turn the fan on/off (and optionally adjust the speed).

Comment: @obclifton I've updated my answer, based on the information you've provided.