# Wiring help needed to bypass ceiling fan remote to light and fan switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I need some wiring help to bypass the remote and directly wire into switches. It is a Makenna 60 inch ceiling fan.

Existing wiring coming from the ceiling is a 12-3 romex connected to a fan speed controller, and light dimmer on the wall.

Below is the PMSM ceiling fan control.
The harnesses at the bottom of the image represent the wires coming from the fan:

- The two wire harness connects to the light
- The three wire harness connects to the fan.

How should the wires be connected to have the light and fan work independently from the wall switch and controller?

[image: Fan Remote]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try this answer: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/83785/157970

Comment: Can you post a link to the manual for your fan?